# ASP.NET Core MVC default model value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my application I'm using CQRS approach. For some queries I wrote IPagedRequest:

```
public interface IPagedRequest<out TResponse>: IRequest<TResponse> { 
    int Page { get; set; } 
    int PageSize { get; set; } 
}
```

My question is: how can I set default values for Page and PageSize properties globally? I tried to use IModelBinder but my code isn't working:

```
public class PagedRequestBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        return typeof(IPagedRequest<object>).IsAssignableFrom(context.Metadata.ModelType)
            ? new PagedRequestBinder()
            : null;
    }
}

public class PagedRequestBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var pagedList = (IPagedRequest<object>) bindingContext.Model;

        if (pagedList.Page == 0) pagedList.Page = 1;
        if (pagedList.PageSize == 0) pagedList.PageSize = 25;

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(pagedList);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the concrete implementation of IPagedRequest? Can't you set default values in constructor?

Comment: @RuiFernandes, I have many implementations of IPagedRequest (e.g. GetProductsRequest, GetCategoriesRequest...). So I want to set default values for paging properties in one place.

Comment: You can create a base class, e.g. RequestBase, and define those properties default values there.

Comment: What is request content type, `application/json` or `form-data`?

Comment: @Edward, application/json

Comment: Is there any issue with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

For binding request body to model, there are two types, one is binding from `Form data` by `[FromForm]` and another is `application/json` by `[FromBody]`.

For `[FromForm]`, it binds model by `IModelBinder`, for `FromBody`, it uses `JsonFormatter`.

For `[FromBody]` in the action, try steps below:

1. Create custom json formatter

   ```
   public class CustomJsonInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
   {
   public CustomJsonInputFormatter(
           ILogger logger,
           JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings,
           ArrayPool<char> charPool,
           ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider,
           MvcOptions options,
           MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions) : base(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider, options, jsonOptions)
   {
   }

   public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   {
       InputFormatterResult result = await base.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context, encoding);
       var pagedList = (IPagedRequest<object>)result.Model;
       if (pagedList != null)
       {
           if (pagedList.Page == 0) pagedList.Page = 1;
           if (pagedList.PageSize == 0) pagedList.PageSize = 25;
       }
       return result;
   }

   }
   ```
2. Register json formatter

   ```
       services.AddMvc(options => {
           var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
           var customJsonInputFormatter = new CustomJsonInputFormatter(
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<CustomJsonInputFormatter>(),
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerSettings,
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ObjectPoolProvider>(),
                    options,
                    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value
               );
           options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, customJsonInputFormatter);

       }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
   ```
3. Controller

   ```
       [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Test([FromBody]PagedRequest<Product> input)
   {
       return Ok(new PagedRequest<Product> {
               Page = 1,
               PageSize = 100
       });
   }
   ```